# How to maintain the same value in a parent and a child component using bi-directional data binding in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components, component A and component B

In Component A , i have two buttons

[image]

Like in picture, I have `Start` and `Stop` buttons. If I click on `Start` button `Stop` button will be enabled and `Start` will be disabled.

Now my problem is if I click on `Start` button and If I navigate to some other page, and if I comeback to page, `Start` button is getting enabled and `Stop` button is getting disabled.

**Expectation is if I click on `Start` button, it should still be in disabled mode and `Stop` button should be on enabled mode when navigated to another component and come back to this component**

```
 <button @click="start" class="start-button" icon-left="play" :disabled="!allowStart">Start</button>

 <button @click="stop" class="stop-button" icon-left="stop" :disabled="allowStart">Stop</button>

 data() {
    return {
     allowStart: true,
    };
  }


start() {
this.allowStart = false; 
}
stop() {
  this.allowStart = true;
}
```

Can anyone help me on this. appreciated the help and response in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the component is being destroyed and re-created when you navigate away and back. In this case, there is no way for the component to remember what the value of `allowStart` was.

Either you have to re-design the component architecture so that this particular component persists when you are navigating, or you need to use some kind of global state management system. The best option would probably be by using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). If you use vuex to store the state of `allowStart`, then when the component is re-created, you can read the value of the state.

If for some reason you don't want to use `vuex`, you could also use the browser's `localStorage`

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried  localStorage.setItem("allowStart",false); in start and stop methods. But no luck.